# Small stuttering white line between animated divs

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm working on my website, and I want to add an animated header that moves like a wave. I've figured out how to get an infinite scroll going, but while my 2 images are moving along the top, they have a small jittery white line between them that can't be fixed by adjusting margins (It looks much more jittery on my actual website vs the codepen). I'm guessing it has something to do with a delay for the css animation? I am new to web development so I could use some advice on how to remove this line to create a seamless effect.

Here is a codepen that replicates the problem:
https://codepen.io/gfreitag/pen/vYvxOgG

HTML:

```
<div class="imcontainer">
  <div class="imWrapper">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/gvpbX3j.png">
  </div>
  <div class="imWrapper">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/gvpbX3j.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imcontainer{
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin:0px;
  font-size:0;
}

.imWrapper{
  display: inline-block; 
  animation: slideAnim 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes slideAnim {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

The only thing different from my actual code is that I'm using Gatsby, so the image is actually a StaticImage component. But the problem still comes up with a standard image tag.

I've tried not wrapping my image in divs, making only the container animate(doesn't work) and adjusting padding and margins. Lots of other small adjustments too.

Comment: Might not be the best fix, but adding `margin: -1px` to `imWrapper` does the trick for me.

Comment: Could you check if adding `backface-visibility: hidden:` property to your `imWrapper` class help?

Comment: @Code_Dummy00 Hey you're right! I could swear I tried that, but it's a decent fix. I would prefer it if it didn't have that little bump though. It will work as a stopgap, but I'm hoping to find a way to stop it altogether.

Comment: @M.ÇağlarTUFAN Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the animation to the parent, not to each element. For example:

```css
html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.img-container {
  display: flex;
  animation: slide 4s linear infinite;
}
.img-container img {
  width: 100%;
}

@keyframes slide {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/gvpbX3j.png">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/gvpbX3j.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, this looks really good! But for some reason, on my actual project, the img-container is taking up 100% of the page instead of the img-container img, making it so the result is shrunk down and just panning both smaller images to the side of the screen. Any idea why? In any case I will accept your answer.