# Safari - white gaps in linear animation

Tags: css, safari, css-animations

I'm having difficulties with an animation on Safari - it works fine everywhere else, but there are these white gaps in a linear looped animation on Safari. I tried different things like setting -webkit-perspective or transform3d- but none seemed to work. What am I missing?

[image]

```css
.animation-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: space-between;
  z-index: 999999;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.animation-waves {
  height: 14vw;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  animation: fadein 4s;
  perspective: 1000;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.animation-waves-item {
  width: 400%;
  transform: translate(-4%);
  background-size: auto 230%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  animation: splash-wave 50s -3s linear infinite;
  opacity: 0.8;
  perspective: 1000;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3csvg width='800' height='209' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'  version='1.1'%3e%3cg%3e%3ctitle%3eLayer 1%3c/title%3e%3cpath id='svg_1' fill='red' clip-rule='evenodd' fill-rule='evenodd' d='m721.33335,44.87378c0,0 0,0 0,0c-4.88889,-1.61705 -9.77778,-2.82984 -14.66667,-4.44689c0,0 0,0 0,0c0,0 0,0 0,0l0,0c-12.66667,-3.63836 -25.33333,-7.68099 -38.22222,-10.91509c0,0 0,0 0,0c-125.55556,-34.36232 -255.55556,-48.91578 -444.00001,13.74493c0,0 -9.33333,2.42558 -24.44445,6.06394c-92.88889,19.40461 -153.11112,18.19182 -181.33334,15.76624c-6.44444,-0.80853 -12.66667,-1.61705 -18.66667,-2.42558l0,145.93881l800.00002,0l0,-138.66208l0,-7.68099c-33.77778,-5.25541 -62.44445,-12.53214 -78.66667,-17.38329z' class='st0'/%3e%3c/g%3e%3c/svg%3e")
}

@keyframes splash-wave {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-4%) translateZ(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-20%) translateZ(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-35%) translateZ(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="animation-wrapper">
    <div class="animation-waves">
      <div class="animation-waves-item">fds</div>
      <div class="animation-waves-item">fs</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try animating to `.animation-waves` instead of `.animation-waves-item` [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77070239/small-stuttering-white-line-between-animated-divs/77074144#77074144)

Comment: My initial guess is that it's possible the `background-repeat` isn't working properly, and so there's a 1px space between the previous image and the new image. (It definitely seems like the 1px gap is between the left and right sides of the repeated image) Have you tried it using an actual `.png` file instead of `data:image/svg`? It's possible it's having trouble rendering the image correctly, and thinks the image has an extra 1px of "white" at the left or right sides of the image.

Comment: (I mean, worst comes to worst, you can create TWO background images, one on top of the other, so that the image underneath will hide the white line. Something like this: `background-image: url(data:image/svg), url(data-image/svg); background-position:0px 0px, 1px 1px;`.But that seems like a last resort.)

Comment: HI, can could you tell us which version of safari are you currently using?
It's kinda difficult to replicate these bugs without the correct version.
Btw i tried 16 > versions, I cannot replicate the bug by copying your code into a blank .html file and using the same css

Answer (score -1):

You can use only CSS to create the wave. I have an [online generator](https://css-generators.com/wavy-shapes/) for this and [a detailed article](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-wavy-shapes-patterns-in-css/) as well

[image: CSS Only wavy generator]

```css
.wave {
   position: fixed;
   inset: auto 0 0;
   height: 200px;
   background: red;
  --mask:
    radial-gradient(127.28px at 50% 180.00px,#000 99%,#0000 101%) 50% 0/360px 100%,
    radial-gradient(127.28px at 50% -90px,#0000 99%,#000 101%) calc(50% + 180px) 90px/360px 100% repeat-x;
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
          mask: var(--mask);
  animation: move 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes move {
  to {
    -webkit-mask-position:
      calc(50% - 360px) 0,
      calc(50% - 180px) 90px
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wave"></div>
```